# IE11 баг calc() в flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer

В IE11 не работает `calc()` в свойстве `flex`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.span {
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}

.span--1 {
  flex: 0 0 calc(4 / 12 * 100% - 5px);
}

.span--2 {
  flex: 0 0 calc(8 / 12 * 100% - 5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <span class="span span--1">4/12</span>
  <span class="span span--2">8/12</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Короткую запись `flex` нужно заменить составляющем `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, `flex-basis`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.span {
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}

.span--1 {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: calc(4 / 12 * 100% - 5px);
}

.span--2 {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: calc(8 / 12 * 100% - 5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <span class="span span--1">4/12</span>
  <span class="span span--2">8/12</span>
</div>
```